# How to avoid C++ segmentation fault with pointer out of scope (polymorphism)

Tags: c++, scope, polymorphism

I'm getting a segmentation fault in my code due to trying to access a pointer value in an if/else block and I think it's because the objects are going out of scope.

The issue is that I need to employ polymorphism and which type of child object I assign the parent type pointers to depends on command line input, so I'm not sure how to avoid the if/else.

The code is below. I know the variable names are bad, by the way, I'm just simplifying them for the sake of this question.

```
P * p1;
P * p2;
B board = B();

if(strcmp(argv[1], "h") == 0) {
   H h = H(board);
   p1 = &h;
} else {
   C c = C(board);
   p1 = &c;
} //else


if(strcmp(argv[2], "h") == 0) {
   H h = H(board);
   p2 = &h;
} else {
   C c = C(board);
   p2 = &c;
} //else   


// Then, if I try to refer to pointer p1, I get a segmentation fault.
// I know why this happens, but am not sure how to fix it.
// For example, this code is problematic:

if(strcmp(argv[1], "h") == 0){
   string n;
   cin >> n;
   p1->setName(n);
} //if
```

I get a segmentation fault when referring to pointers p1 and p2 after this. I know this is because the objects of type H and C are going out of scope after my if/else blocks but I'm not sure how I should fix it. Would putting H and C objects on the heap work? Or maybe declaring the H and C objects outside of the if statement?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Allocate the objects dynamically. Then you can keep them alive until you kill them. Preferably with a `unique_ptr` for example

Comment: instead of `p1 = &h;` you can write `p1 = new H(board);`, don't forget to `delete p1;` at the end

Comment: You can also return *objects* by value (not pointers), provided you have suitable move constructors. (I mean, you can always do that, move constructors or not, but it will be inefficient.)

Comment: Thanks so much! So deleting p1 will take care of that H object too?

Comment: "Would putting H and C objects on the heap work? Or maybe declaring the H and C objects outside of the if statement?" - I think both will work, actually. The second point can be refined to declare the objects and use the pointer `p1` _in the same scope_.

Comment: Okay, I put the references on the heap but for some reason I am still getting a segmentation fault when trying to access any of the methods in the objects pointed to by p1 or p2 later in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commend you for diagnosing the source of the problem.

The simplest solution will be to allocate `H` and `C` using dynamic memory allocation and use the returned pointers.

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "h") == 0) {
   p1 = new H(board);
} else {
   p1 = new C(board);
}
```

Do the same for `p2`.

Add code to release the dynamically allocated memory before the end of the function.

```
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

---

You can use a smart pointer to make the deallocation easier.

```
std::unique_ptr<P> p1;
std::unique_ptr<P> p2;

...

if(strcmp(argv[1], "h") == 0) {
   p1.reset(new H(board));
} else {
   p1.reset(new C(board));
}
```

By using `std::unique_ptr`, you won't need the lines for deleting the pointers.

Comment: Thanks! As type P is abstract I'm getting a warning (because there's a non-virtual destructor)... this means I just have to define a virtual destructor in the base class?

Comment: Okay, I put the references on the heap but for some reason I am still getting a segmentation fault when trying to access any of the methods in the objects pointed to by p1 or p2.

Comment: @Himani, please post a [mcve]. Without that, it's hard telling where the problem(s) could be.

Comment: @R Sahu, Okay I understand, but as there are many files involved (both headers and .cpp files mean there's overall around 9 or 10 files I'd have to share) I think it might just be too complicated. Thanks for your help anyway, I'll try to work on figuring it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate dynamically. I recommend using [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers). Here is an example:

```
std::unique_ptr<P> p1;
if(cond)
  p1.reset(new H(board));
```

You can use a raw pointer too, but then you need to manage the lifetime yourself.